# setFieldsToNull method not working in a custom webservice class

Tags: webservices

We have a Salesforce custom webservice; this custom webservice is consumed by an external application.

This custom webervice supports an upsert on Contact object and the source application is trying to make the middle name blank in Salesforce using custom upsert.

Below is a sample code which we are using in our custom webservice class:

```
Contact cnt=new Contact();
        cnt.lastname ='LNAME';
        cnt.setFieldsToNull(new String[]{'MiddleName'});
```

**Error:** Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setFieldsToNull(List) from the type Contact

Can anyone please let us know, how do we make Salesforce to update null values through custom webservice.

Comment: This is Apex Code?

Answer (score 1):

`SetFieldsToNull` is not a provided Salesforce method for any object, including `Contact`. You have to write it yourself. Thankfully, it should be a real simple function to write using apex:

```
public static sObject SetFieldsToNull(sObject record, List<String> fields) {
    for (String field:fields) {
        record.put(field, null);
    }

    return record; 
}

// Call like this: 

Contact someContact = new Contact();

someContact = (Contact)SetFieldsToNull(someContact, new List<String>{ 'MiddleName' });
```